# Fixed position of content until parent div ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a piece of code that gets fixed while y-scoll is over 765px. The problem is that this content will be fixed even outside its parent. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/rwbsua3v/

As you can see, while you keep scrolling, the content in the green box gets fixed and will override the blue box as you scroll.

I could fix this issue if I knew the exact heights of the red/green and blue boxes but the problem is that they can be of any length. How would I make the content in the green box fixed until it hits the bottom of parent (green box) without affecting the y-scroll offset and css top: 87px?

Here is my code:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var floating1 = document.getElementById("floating1");

var yOffset = 765;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > yOffset) {
    floating1.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    floating1.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 2000px;
}

table tr td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed!important;
  top: 87px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="background: red; width: 200px;">
      ...
    </td>
    <td style="background: green; width: 200px;">
      <div id="floating1">
        Floating content
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div style="height: 1500px; background: blue;">
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`position: sticky`](https://medium.com/@elad/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46) that makes the element fixed in place until it encounters the edge of it's container:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var floating1 = document.getElementById("floating1");

var yOffset = 765;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > yOffset) {
    floating1.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    floating1.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 2000px;
}

table tr td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 87px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="background: red; width: 200px;">
      ...
    </td>
    <td style="background: green; width: 200px;">
      <div id="floating1">
        Floating content
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div style="height: 1500px; background: blue;">
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/17rn4qtw/2/.

1. I added `id="parent"` to the parent of the floating content and used Javascript to get its height.
2. I addded a second `if` clause in the function that only fixes the floating content if the page offset if less than the div content height.

I also subtracted the top pixels from the height of the parent so the floating content disappeared a when outside of the parent, not just when the parent was outside of the window view.

Answer (score 0):

add a class `green` to your div and check when it reaches an end.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var floating1 = document.getElementById("floating1");

var yOffset = 765;

function myFunction() {
 if (window.pageYOffset > yOffset && window.pageYOffset < $('.green').height()) {
   floating1.classList.add("sticky");
  } else if (window.pageYOffset > $('.green').height()) {
   floating1.classList.remove("sticky");
  } else {
   floating1.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 2000px;
}

table tr td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed!important;
  top: 87px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td style="background: red; width: 200px;">
    ...
  </td>
  <td style="background: green; width: 200px;" class="green">
    <div id="floating1">
      Floating content
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
<div style="height: 1500px; background: blue;">
  ...
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/djkog8ft/